# With You, Without You. A Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> YOU CAME
>   I was a miserable drunk and you were kind.
>   I was sick and you took away my emptiness.
>   You took me from my secret haunt and gave me talent.
>   You turned my space to celebration.
>   Always, you gave me warmth.
>
> BUT
>   You departed, I allowed it.
>
> WITHOUT YOU
>   I had something to give, but that is past.
>   My influences are mere pretenders.
>   My weapon is gone, leaving only anger.
>   My very being has become a sham.

Name the subject of this riddle.

Comment: I'm back! Are you happy now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The subject is

> the letter F.

---

I was a miserable drunk and you were kind.

> sot $\Rightarrow$ soft

I was sick and you took away my emptiness.

> ill $\Rightarrow$ fill

You took me from my secret haunt and gave me talent.

> lair $\Rightarrow$ flair

You turned my space to celebration.

> air $\Rightarrow$ fair (from @HerbWolfe)

Always, you gave me warmth.

> ever $\Rightarrow$ fever

You departed, I allowed it.

> left $\Rightarrow$ let

I had something to give, but that is past.

> offer $\Rightarrow$ o'er

My influences are mere pretenders.

> factors $\Rightarrow$ actors

My weapon is gone, leaving only anger.

> fire $\Rightarrow$ ire (from @HerbWolfe) or
> rifle $\Rightarrow$ rile

My very being has become a sham.

> life $\Rightarrow$ lie

Comment: Space is air. Anger could be ire. Not sure on the something to give or past.

Comment: So, f'', is this the story of your life?

Comment: I had something to give, but that is past. fended -> ended?

Comment: "had something to give, but that is past."  Maybe like git -> gift?  Slang spelling might not be desirable, but it fits...

Comment: And "offer -> o'er" which, I admit, is a bit off. Well done, ". It couldn't have been solved by a more appropriate letter. The weapon was a rifle.